# Sedgewick - Algorithms 4 Libraries

Tags: java, ubuntu, classpath

I'm trying to use the algs4 libraries for the Sedgewick's book Algorithms 4 and the things aren't working.

I think I'm following correctly the guide from the website http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/code/.

I saved the files stdlib.jar and algs4.jar in the directory ~/algs4 and append the line "export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:~/algs4/stdlib.jar:~/algs4/algs4.jar" in the ~/.profile file.

The things should work, right? 
Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What exceptions are you getting actually? Stacktraces would be helpful.

Comment: The compiler is claiming that it can't find the symbols used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run

```
. ~/.profile
```

to refresh your profile?

**EDIT**

Normally running a command in Linux will create a new subshell and execute that.  This means that any variables set in the command will be lost when the subshell exits.  To make the variables persist, you can either export them or run the command in the current shell by using the source or . command.

**EDIT**

To know what your profile file is, you need to know which shell you are running.  Use the ps command and see what the CMD is:

```
$ ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
17692 pts/5    00:00:00 zsh
23736 pts/5    00:00:00 ps
```

This shows that I am running the zsh shell.  If you just see sh, you can't immediately tell, so you should try running

```
sh --version
```

Comment: New Problem. Every time I reboot the system I need to refresh the profile, otherwise I can't use the libraries. What can I do to solve this?

Comment: If you are running the bash shell, then you should set the classpath in ~/.bash_profile instead.  .profile is used by the Bourne shell.

Comment: I did set the classpath in ~/.profile because it was the only one in my system. Should I create the ~/.bash_profile?

Comment: Yes if you are running bash.

Comment: I'm afraid to damage the system doing it. The .profile says "This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login exists."

Comment: You are right.  According to the man page, bash looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile in  that order.

Comment: So there's no way to solve this problem without the danger of breaking my system?

Comment: The profiles are only read by login shells.  Try modifying the classpath in ~/.bashrc instead.  See [http://serverfault.com/questions/8882/what-is-the-difference-between-a-login-and-an-interactive-bash-shell] (this post) for an explanation of the different kinds of shell.